# Storing different types of Portable objects under parent on Hazelcast

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

So I have a Cart object which implements the Portable interface. I need to store different types of product objects (all of which implement Portable) under Cart object. I guess there's no problem when storing the child portable objects, calling WritePortable works. I don't know how to type-cast child portables to appropriate type while reading the portable.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do it in an provided way. Portable objects behave likes Maps / Dictionaries. However you can add the type name or an type identifier as a property which is written to the Portable stream itself. That way you can read it back in and make your cast-decision based on that.

Sorry for not having a better way but it'll work :)

Comment: That was my first attempt but I thought there may be a better way. Thanks.